# How to add extra info to realm SyncUser

Tags: java, realm

I want to add extra info to SyncUser in realm, like isActivated and phoneNumber.
Should I generate another RealmObject and put data there or can I add some info directly into syncUser credentials.

Signing up and logging using:

```
SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, true/false);
```

And also how to connect multiple social accounts to it...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it isn't possible to add metadata to users directly. You can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4645 for progress on that.

For now, the best way would probably be to create a Realm file with that information, something like:

```
public class UserInfo extends RealmObject {
  public String twitterId;
  public String facebookId;
  ...
}

@RealmModule(classes = { UserInfo.class })
public class UserInfoModule {
}

SyncConfiguration config = new SynConfiguration().Builder(getUser(), getUrl())
    .modules(new UserInfoModule())
    .build();
```